Passing session variable from list php
I am having a major issue passing session variables via link from a list of options.
Having searched through numerous posts I havent seen anything that is of help.
So here is a sample of the code.
enter code heresession_start();
enter code hereforeach($clients as $client){
enter code here$_SESSION['name']=$client ->user_name;
enter code here$_SESSION['title']=$client ->user_title;
enter code here$_SESSION['client_id']=$client ->user_id;
enter code here$_SESSION['info']=$client ->user_info;
enter code here$_SESSION['type']=$client ->user_type;
enter code here$_SESSION['project_ref']=$client ->user_project_ref;
enter code here$_SESSION['client_project']=$client ->user_project;
enter code here$client_id=$_SESSION['client_id'];
}
Then in the list we have
enter code here
in the 'client' page we have
enter code heresession_start();
enter code hereif(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
enter code here$_SESSION['client_id'];
enter code here$_SESSION['name'] ;
enter code here$_SESSION['title'];
enter code here$_SESSION['info'];
enter code here$_SESSION['type'];
enter code here$_SESSION['project'];//echo $project;
enter code here$_SESSION['ref']; }
enter code here<?php $clients=$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( " SELECT * FROM vo_wp_clients where user_id= '$client_id'"));
The page opens but the result is incorrect.
If I echo the session variables it shows the settings for the wrong entry.
I'm sure I am missing something straightforward but any help would be very helpful

It sounds like you’re running into some issues with session variables when trying to select clients from a list.
In my current PHP project, I'm facing similar issues, so I can definitely help you to navigate this situation!
This Things can help you to get the Output.

Pass the client_id via a URL query parameter.
Retrieve client details on the target page based on the client_id.
Set session variables only after fetching the correct client data.
Make sure to sanitize inputs to prevent SQL injection.

1. Display the List of Clients
// When displaying clients
    foreach ($clients as $client) {
        echo '<a href="client_page.php?client_id=' . $client->user_id . '">' . $client->user_name . '</a>';
    }

2. Set Session Variables on the Client Page
client_page.php


<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_GET['client_id'])) {
    $client_id = intval($_GET['client_id']); // Sanitize input
    // Query to get the client info
    $clients = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM vo_wp_clients WHERE user_id = %d", $client_id));

    if (!empty($clients)) {
        $client = $clients[0]; // Get the first client record
        $_SESSION['name'] = $client->user_name;
        $_SESSION['title'] = $client->user_title;
        $_SESSION['client_id'] = $client->user_id;
        $_SESSION['info'] = $client->user_info;
        $_SESSION['type'] = $client->user_type;
        $_SESSION['project_ref'] = $client->user_project_ref;
        $_SESSION['client_project'] = $client->user_project;
    }
}

// In this way now you can use the session variables as needed
if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['name'];
    echo $_SESSION['title'];
    echo $_SESSION['info'];
    // and so on...
}


?>




Thank you so much
that appears to have sorted the problem
That has been bursting my brain for the last week!

Maybe this is a daft question, but shouldnt client_id=2103702968 be hidden?
